# Recursive value needs type error in Scala 3 implicit parameter

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-3

I'm trying to compile the following code in Scala 3 (worked on Scala 2.13):

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._

@main
def main(): Unit = {
  case class AAA(d: FiniteDuration)

  val duration1 = 5.seconds
  implicit val what = AAA(duration1)
}
```

But getting the following error:

> Recursive value duration1 needs type   implicit val what =
> AAA(duration1)

Making the parameter non implicit fixed the error. Why?

Comment: What do you mean by _"Making the parameter non implicit"_ - what "parameter"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._

@main
def main(): Unit = {
  case class AAA(d: FiniteDuration)

  val duration1 = 5.seconds
  implicit val what: AAA = AAA(duration1)
}
```

or

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._

@main
def main(): Unit = {
  case class AAA(d: FiniteDuration)

  val duration1 = 5.seconds
  given AAA = AAA(duration1)
}
```

As a general guideline: always explicitly ascribe the type of all givens / implicits. It's an assignment for a compile-time type-level computation, it's better to specify what type you are assigning the given value to.

Comment: thank you, took your advice further and replaced "implicit val what = AAA(duration1)" with "given AAA(duration1)" and the error is gone. still wonder why implicit val with no explicit type declaration gave the cryptic compiler error.

Comment: from the migration guide: "The type of implicit definitions (val or def) needs to be given explicitly in Scala 3. They cannot be inferred anymore." I wonder just why the compiler error is so not related.